# DataInputStream reading the wrong

Tags: android, bluetooth, datainputstream, bufferedinputstream

So I have an android app streaming data from an Arudino connected to my car through bluetooth, I'm trying to stream data as ints, and so far it is working using a Buffered Input Stream and Data Input Stream, but the values are extremely large as opposed to what the value should be
the continuos Arudino stream looks like:

```
-11 0 0 12400...
```

And the Data Input Stream see's it as something super large like 875573296 for each number

This is my method I am currently using, this is from my computer but I'm getting the same results Android app or computer:

```
BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(portPicked.getInputStream()); 
DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream (reader);

try {
while(true){
                System.out.println(inputStream.readInt());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Really simple, I feel like I'm missing something, on my computer it works using a Scanner, and on my android app it works using some other code but the problem is that it takes the value in as a String, and I need it as an int.

Thank you!

Comment: How are these integers sent to the client? Is there a JVM running on the Arudino?

Comment: The reason I ask is the bit-ordering (endianness) may differ, resulting in an obscenely wrong integer. If you are sending from Java, however, all  `int`s are of big endianness, so that would not be your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it's using a Serial.print((int)someNumber) function, they use an ASCII format. Can't find anything about the bit-ordering, but if there is a way to change it to little endianness I could try